# Correctly calling method which refers to instance in ProvidedConstructor

Tags: f#, type-providers

How do I properly supply the code to a `ProvidedConstructor`'s `InvokeCode` in a generative type provider which would do the equivalent of the following?

Given:

```
module Utils =
    let someFun (s : string) (inst : obj) =
          // Does something here...
          ()
```

I need to have the generated type effectively do:

```
type NewGeneratedType () as self =
     inherit BaseType ()

     do
         Utils.someFun "Foo" (box self)
```

I have the call to the base constructor working, but don't know how to properly slice in the instance and get the function called:

```
let ctor = ProvidedConstructor([])
let ci = baseType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.Instance, null, [|  |], null)
ctor.BaseConstructorCall <- fun args -> ci, args 

// I do not know how to properly call this to match the constructor above
ctor.InvokeCode <- fun args -> <@@ () @@>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this working via:

```
ctor.InvokeCode <- 
    fun args -> 
        let this = Seq.head args
        let boxed = Expr.Coerce(this, typeof<obj>)
        <@@  Utils.someFun "Foo" %%(boxed) @@>
```

Note that trying to move the first two lines into the splice caused all sorts of errors, but when I pull it out, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

it looks like a ["this" argument is passed in as the last argument to the ctor](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack/blob/master/src/ProvidedTypes.fs#L1323)

From there your InvokeCode function [will get run](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack/blob/master/src/ProvidedTypes.fs#L584) and the returned quotation translated. So, i think all you need is something like:

```
ctor.InvokeCode <- fun args -> <@@ let me = Seq.last args @@>
```

Comment: `this` is always first. `xs |> List.append x` is equal to `List.append x xs` and equeal to `x::xs`

Comment: Note that trying to use this always gives a type mismatch error: `Type mismatch when splicing expression into quotation literal. The type of the expression tree being inserted doesn't match the type expected by the splicing operation. Expected 'NewGeneratedType', but received type 'System.Object'. Consider type-annotating with the expected expression type, ...`  Nothing I try seems to allow me to work around this.

Comment: BTW - This helped get me there - posted what was required at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37172942/65358  Thanks @CAIndy

Answer (score 1):

@Reed Copsey, I'm thinking you need to call your own constructor actually:

assuming you NewGeneratedType is a concrete type you have defined already

```fsharp
<@@ let this = (ctor.Invoke([||])) :> NewGeneratedType
    Utils.someFun "foo" (box this)
@@>
```

If NewGeneratedType is not defined but is also a provided type itself, you'll need a Expr.Coerce:

```fsharp
<@@ let this = (ctor.Invoke([||]))
    let thisTyped = %%Expr.Coerce(this, providedType)
    Utils.someFun "foo" (box this)
@@>
```

I'm not 100% sure this function but I hope this will get you in the way.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding `ctor.Invoke` reports the erorr `... reported an error: unknown constant 'ProviderImplementation.ProvidedTypes.ProvidedConstructor' in generated method`